# D3.JS SVG Rectangles don't appear

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to create grouped bar chart like in this example http://bl.ocks.org/kpq/6695897 with the difference that instead of 3 columns with 2 bars each I want 1 column with 3 bars.

I wrote code to create basic shapes but rectangles don't appear. Screen is just blank. I am not so experienced with d3 and also console doesn't show any error so I can't spot my mistake.

`y0`, `y1` and `x1` are scales and they work fine.

Code:

```
 var year = svg.selectAll(".g-year")
     .data(nestedData)
     .enter()
     .append("g")
     .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + y0(d.key) + 
     ")" })
     .append("text")
     .text(function(d) { return d.key; })
     .attr("dy", 20)
     .attr("dx", -100);

 var metric = year.append('g')
     .selectAll('.g-metric-bars')
     .data(function (d) {
         return d.values;
     })
     .enter()
     .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'g-metric-bars')
     .attr('transform', function (d) {
         return 'translate(0 ,' + y1(d.key) + ')';
     })
     .append('g')
     .attr('class','bar')
     .append('rect')
     .attr('width', function(d){
         return x1(d.value);
     })
     .attr('height', y1.bandwidth())
     .attr('transform',function (d,i) {
         return "translate(0," + y1.bandwidth() + ")";
     })
     .attr('fill', 'black');
```

Screen:

[image: No rectangles]
html:

[image: Generated code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After appending a `<text>` element, your `year` selection is actually just a text selection:

```
var year = svg.selectAll(".g-year")
     .data(nestedData)
     .enter()
     .append("g")
     .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + y0(d.key) + 
     ")" })
     .append("text")//from here on, a text selection
     .text(function(d) { return d.key; })
     .attr("dy", 20)
     .attr("dx", -100);
```

And, since a `<text>` element cannot hold groups (`<g>`), you have the explanation for your blank screen.

The solution is simple: break your selection:

```
var year = svg.selectAll(".g-year")
     .data(nestedData)
     .enter()
     .append("g")
     .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + y0(d.key) + 
     ")" });

var foo = year.append("text")
     .text(function(d) { return d.key; })
     .attr("dy", 20)
     .attr("dx", -100);
```

That way, `year` is an enter selection containing `<g>` elements.